# Retrieve POST data of the current web page in a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I can get the current page URL in a Firefox extension but I'd like to get the POST data too. Firefox stores it somewhere to send it again on refresh. How can I get it from my extension ?

I could probably capture each request like Firebug, but I'd rather avoid that and get the POST data only on demand.

I'm using the [add-on SDK (jetpack)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/). I tried the code from [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous#Getting_postData_of_a_webpage) in my main script:

```
{Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");

wm = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);
mainWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

history = mainWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.webNavigation.sessionHistory;

postdata = history.getEntryAtIndex(history.index-1,false).QueryInterface(Ci.nsISHEntry).postData;

postdata.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISeekableStream).seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);
stream = Cc["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIBinaryInputStream);
stream.setInputStream(postdata);
postBytes = stream.readByteArray(stream.available());
poststr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, postBytes);

console.log(poststr);
```

But it fails at

```
postdata.QueryInterface(Ci.nsISeekableStream).seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);
```

Because `postdata is null` (`TypeError`).

I also tried this method in a content script attached to the active tab, but it fails with a permission denied while getting `Components.classes`.

Comment: This works fine for me (I shortened `mainWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.webNavigation.sessionHistory` into `mainWindow.gBrowser.sessionHistory` but otherwise it's the same). Are you sure that the history entry you are looking at has POST data associated with it? Note that webservers will often redirect after receiving POST data - in that case the current history entry won't have any POST data (and you won't see a warning if your try to reload the page).

Comment: The current page has POST data (I hit refresh and the dialog shows up). But actually, this code retrieves the POST data of the last page, not the current one. I fixed this by simply removing the `-1`. Thank you for your help. Knowing this code works helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code retrieves the POST data of the last page, not the current one.

I changed `history.index-1` to `history.index` and it works.